# I'm trying to make my 2D unity character jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as I said, I'm trying to make my character jump in Unity, but nothing is happening when I hit space, and Unity isn't throwing any errors.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    [SerializeField]
    public float jumpSpeed;

    private Animator myAnimator;

    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed;

    private bool facingLeft;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] groundPoints;

    [SerializeField]
    private float groundRadius;

    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private bool isGrounded;

    private bool jump;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        facingLeft = true;
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Debug.Log(horizontal);

        isGrounded = IsGrounded();

        HandleMovement(horizontal);

        flip(horizontal);

    }

    private void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
    {

        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * movementSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

        myAnimator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));

        if (isGrounded && jump)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            myRigidbody. AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
        }

    }

    private void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jump = true;
        }
    }

    private void flip(float horizontal)
    {
        if (horizontal < 0 && !facingLeft || horizontal > 0 && facingLeft)
        {
            facingLeft = !facingLeft;

            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

            theScale.x *= -1;

            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if (myRigidbody.velocity.y <= 0)
        {
            foreach (Transform point in groundPoints)
            {
                Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

                for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I've been following [this](https://youtu.be/05TCTrpGB-4) tutorial for it, and his is jumping, but mine isn't. I think it might have something to do with the way I have the groundpoints set up, but I'm not sure if it's a error in the code or if it's in Unity.

Comment: For some reason the first line of code didn't show up in the code box, it is supposed to be in there.

Comment: Is the script attached to the gameObject and the values filled in the serialized fields?? Why fixed update instead regular update??

Comment: Why do you think that the error comes from groundPoints set up? how did you configure them?

Comment: "Why fixed update instead regular update??" So that the speed of the game doesn't change depending on your fps.

Comment: "Why do you think that the error comes from groundPoints set up? how did you configure them?" Mostly just because this is the first time I'm doing this and I think I might've messed up, I have three groundpoints on the character, one on the bottom left corner, one on the bottom right corner, and one in the middle of those two.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling HandleInput anywhere.

add to fixed update

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Debug.Log(horizontal);

isGrounded = IsGrounded();

HandleMovement(horizontal);

flip(horizontal);

HandleInput(); // add this so you are sampling input

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I added this to the code, nothing changed.